# Use offset of Windowstart in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I wish to incrementally copy data from azure table to azure blob. I have created linked services, datasets and pipelines. I wish to copy data from table to blob after every hour. The table has a timestamp column.I want to transfer data from table to blob in such a way that the data which gets added to the table from 7am to 8am should be pushed to blob in activity window starting at 8 am. In other words, I don't want to miss any data flowing into the table.

Comment: So are you wanting some overlap in the time slice executions or something? Sorry, I'm not really following your dump of text. Could you please rewrite it so it makes sense and structured as a question? Thanks

Comment: $$Text.Format('PartitionKey ge \'{0:yyyyMMddHH}\' and PartitionKey lt \'{1:yyyyMMddHH}\'',WindowStart, WindowEnd)

Comment: Using the above query, if activity windows starts at 6 and ends at 6:15, the rows with timestamp 6-6:15 will come and I will miss rows with timestamp 6:15-7

Comment: For have you looked at the ADF time slice 'offset' attribute?

Comment: Yeah i tried using it, but still i was unable to get all records

Comment: @palakarora post the answer if you managed to solve it. I am facing the same issue.  I am thinking of using `WindowStart.AddHours(-1) with merge.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed the query used to extract data from the azure table.

```
"azureTableSourceQuery": "$$Text.Format('PartitionKey gt \\'{0:yyyyMMddHH} \\' and PartitionKey le \\'{1:yyyyMMddHH}\\'', Time.AddHours(WindowStart, -2), Time.AddHours(WindowEnd, -2))"
```

This query will get data which was added to the table 2 hours back and hence I wont miss any data.